# What engine do I have, based on my casting number?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, gmc

I have a 1965 GMC TRUCK 3 speed short bed stepside.  The casting number is `TI1I3CZM`.  How can I figure out what engine I have?

My truck is a step side short bed Chevy.

Comment: See this link to get the proper casting number on the engine block....https://www.enginelabs.com/news/reference-chevy-engine-block-casting-numbers/

Comment: Might be hard to find casting numbers for 6 cylinder blocks, above is for small block chevrolet.

Comment: @Moab That link doesn't work for me.  Would that be something you could put in an answer?

Comment: I am not sure it applies to you, we need a better idea of what engine it is, V8, inline6, V6 , cubic inch, anything will help.

Comment: Does the chassis have a data-plate?